# asp.net webform pattern re-use same page (view and edit)

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

i'm working on a project which aim is to create a sort of social portal.

The matter is that i've an entity page detail where user can edit it or just view it.
I'm considering to create just one page and using that as view only and edit mode at the same time. 
I had two ideas:

1) create an enumeration ControlBehaviour { EditMode, ViewMode } in Session and using that to understand if I have to set readonly every controls in my page;

2) use jquery to set readonly every controls in the page if i have to open it in viewmode (or not readonly if i have to open it in edit mode).

Does it exist any pattern to reach my aim?
best regards

Comment: If the difference between viewing data and editing data is role-based and a security concern, disabling the form elements on the client-side is a bad idea.  Users can re-enable them and post edits.

Comment: hey david! i didn't think that! damn ... do you know if a pattern exists to reach my aim?

Comment: I've generally found it best to keep viewing and editing on separate pages.  But that by itself is a very broad and sweeping statement and doesn't apply in all cases.  For you needs all I can really suggest is that you don't try to get too "clever" with the design.  Properly separated logical concerns with easy to support code is a lot better than saving a few bytes of code and condensing functionality.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't know hot to flag your answer as the corret one :(

Comment: It's technically not an answer, just a comment.  I don't think I really "answered" your question so much as just offered advice, so no flagging necessary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating your concerns into read and edit forms is most suitable, in terms of maintaining your code afterwards, by yourself or for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The DetailsView control is exactely what you are looking for

Comment: hi citronas. I read a bit of docs on DetailsView and it says everywhere that detailsview need sql data source. I've a more complex infrastructure, with Entity Framework Model and POCO objects. I read data from db using a Repository project. Then i've an Infrastructure project where i map those entities to dto object. Dtos' are used on aspx files to show values. I'm searching for a different solution rather than a server side control like DetailsView. I'd like to know if a pattern exist to reach my aim

Comment: You can bind the DetailsView to a custom business object